# Display Query Results in Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

So I have a series of stored procs that return different columns and results.  I want to build a report where the user can select the query and have that queries results display in the details.

Is there a way to embed a query grid OR an excel type grid (display) into a report?

In access, I could add a subform and pretty much throw any query in datasheet view in there and wouldn't have to define columns for display purposes.

Input: 
@storedproc1  @territory

Output: 
stored proc results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to build a table to display the results, it won't just display all the columns from your query automatically or anything.

Probably the closest thing to what you're wanting would be to build a table per stored proc and have visibility conditions, coupled with a parameter to allow the user to select which stored proc they want to view data for.

Comment: Makes sense.  I was hoping I could just plug in stored procs and not have to update a table every time.  No biggie.

Thanks for the response